# how to display particular value when enter the building name and click view button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have using Kendo UI dropdownlist and one kendo masked textbox and one view button in kendo,i want to load all country in dropdownlist and select particular country corresponding given building name in textbox and click view button pls help

I am using mvc4 razor in view page design the kendo dropdownlist

my view page code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#viewbutton").click(function(){
       $.ajax({
       type:'post',
       data:{name:Buildingname},
       url:'@url.Action("GetCountry");
       success:function(data)
       {
          //response particular country name and value  also all country name
         //next what will i do 
         //how to select corresponding country name
       }
    });
});
```

My controller code is:

```
public JsonResult GetCountry(string name = null)
{ 
    dataTable dt;
    if(name == null)
    {
       dt = bal.country();
       for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           ListName.Add(new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = dt.Rows[i]["CountryId"].Tostring(),
               Text = dt.Rows[i]["CountryName"].Tostring()
           });
       }
       return Json(new SelectList(ListName, "Value", "Text"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   else
   {
       dt = bal.country(name);
       ListName.Add(new SelectListItem
       {
          Value = dt.Rows[i]["CountryId"].Tostring(),
          Text = dt.Rows[i]["CountryName"].Tostring()
       });
       return Json(new SelectList(ListName," Value", "Text"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
   }
}
```

Comment: Is your ajax method returning result?

Comment: @JitendraYadav yes sir returned the json  data in array format  ex: data[0].Text and data[0].Value

Comment: Its pointless extra overhead to create `List<SelectListItem>` and then create a new `SelectList` from it (its already one) and the to return a `SelectList` (the browser has no knowledge of a c# class). Just return a collection of anonymous objects containing 2 properties, one for the `value` attribute of the `<option>` and one for the display text

Comment: @StephenMuecke json return object and ajax method response value ex:data.Text data.Value sir value is k but how to i set that value of  selecteditem in dropdownlist?

Comment: Do you mean you want one of the options you generate to be selected? What is you logic for selecting an option - nothing in your code indicates which option would be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data,function(i,item){
 var dropdownlist = $("#mydropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");        
        if(item.Selected==true){
            dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
              return dataItem.Text=== item.Text;
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Change code as below in cs.

```
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
       {
           ListName.Add(new SelectListItem
           {
               Value = dt.Rows[i]["CountryId"].Tostring(),
               Text = dt.Rows[i]["CountryName"].Tostring()
               Selected=dt.Rows[i]["You respective field"].Tostring().Equals(name)?true:false
           });
       }
```

In javascript:

```
$.each(data,function(i,item){
    //To add item in kedo dropdown use this code
$("#mydropdownlist").data("kendoComboBox").dataSource.add({ text: item.Text, value: item.Value });
});
```

To select particular Item:

```
$.each(data,function(i,item){
 var dropdownlist = $("#mydropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");        
        if(item.Selected==true){
            dropdownlist.select(function(dataItem) {
              return dataItem.symbol === item.Text;
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: i want  selected item corresponding country name dynamically in kendo dropdownlist to given name also load all country name sir.

Comment: not working sir, i want display country name in header text in dropdownlist  corresponding building name search

Comment: @vinothpalaniraj I have added "Selected" property which will give you the country corresponding building name, based on that you can set. What do you mean in header text?

Comment: i mean header text selected text.